# multiple navigation properties to the same table using code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have a one-to-many relationship setup. IT is working fine but now I am trying to use pdfsharp and I need some help with the navigation properties. Every Measurement has 4 pictures. Front, Back, Right, Left. I need to include all 4 pics in the pdf. I am unable to reach them with what i have now. I can return the list of pictures per measurement in a table. Just dont know how to change it for this to work as well.

```
 public class Measurement
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MeasurementDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? BustMeasurement { get; set; }
    public decimal? ChestMeasurement { get; set; }
    public decimal? FAT { get; set; }

    public string MeasurementUploadBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MeasurementUploadDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MeasurementEditDate { get; set; }
    public string MeasurementEditBy { get; set; }

    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
}

  public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PictureFrontUrl { get; set; }
    public string PictureBackUrl { get; set; }
    public string PictureRightSideUrl { get; set; }
    public string PictureLeftSideUrl { get; set; }
    public string PictureNote { get; set; }
    public string PictureUploadBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PictureUploadDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PictureDate { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string PictureType { get; set; }
    public Guid MeasurementId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MeasurementId")]
    public virtual Measurement Measurement { get; set; }
}
```

MeasurementApi

```
public Measurement GetMeasurement(Guid id)
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            Measurement model = new Measurement();
            model = context.Measurements
               .Include(x => x.Pictures)
               .FirstOrDefault(j => j.Id == id);
            return model;
        }
    }
```

PDFSharp GEt Call

```
apiMeasurementController adapter = new apiMeasurementController();
        Measurement model = new Measurement();
        model = adapter.GetMeasurement(id);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You are not getting the pictures along with the measurement? Could you post the SQL that gets generated?

Comment: Or do you want 4 properties? `Picture Left` `Picture Top` `Picture Right` `Picture Bottom`

Comment: In the pdfsharp controller when I need to be able to do model.pictures. picturefronturl.    Right now I get nothing with model.pictures.    I will post SQL in about it 20 minutes

Comment: Yes I need all four pics that r attached to the measurement

Comment: If model.Pictures is empty, then its because 1. EF has not mapped correctly or 2. There are no pictures for that specific measurement in the database.

Comment: at the moment, it looks like every measurement can have many pictures, and every picture has 4 urls. Is that correct? Or do you want every measurement to just have 4 pictures?

Comment: Then you should have 4 foreign keys on your Measurement, along with 4 `Picture` navigational properties, rather than having a collection of pictures. Then each picture wouldn't need 4 URLs, onyl 1 URL

Comment: can u show me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your Measurement to have 4 pictures, and not a colleciton of pictures you should have something like this:

```
public class Measurement
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ....

    // Won't need these
    // public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }


    public virtual Picture LeftPicture { get; set; }

    public virtual Picture TopPicture { get; set; }

    public virtual Picture RightPicture { get; set; }

    public virtual Picture BottomPicture { get; set; }
}
```

And your picture:

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Don't need these 4 any more.
    // public string PictureFrontUrl { get; set; }
    // public string PictureBackUrl { get; set; }
    // public string PictureRightSideUrl { get; set; }
    // public string PictureLeftSideUrl { get; set; }

    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }

    public string PictureNote { get; set; }
    public string PictureUploadBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PictureUploadDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PictureDate { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string PictureType { get; set; }
    public Guid MeasurementId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MeasurementId")]
    public virtual Measurement Measurement { get; set; }
}
```

And in your API

```
public Measurement GetMeasurement(Guid id)
{
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        Measurement model = new Measurement();
        model = context.Measurements
           .Include(x => x.LeftPicture)
           .Include(x => x.TopPicture)
           .Include(x => x.RightPicture)
           .Include(x => x.BottomPicture)
           .FirstOrDefault(j => j.Id == id);
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: dont i need a single pictureurl?

Comment: Yes sorry, you will do