# How to represent a relationship between a parent and multiple child properties of the same type?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Consider the following two entities<sup>*</sup>:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Child PrimaryChild { get; set; }
    public virtual Child SecondaryChild { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Foreign keys to be added here or
    // in the other class (that's what I'm trying to figure out)
}
```

As the code shows, a parent needs to have a primary child and a secondary child; and (preferably) when the parent is deleted, both children should be deleted as well.

**Is it even possible to represent such relationship with EF?**

If the parent were to have only one child, I could easily use a one-to-one relationship (`1 to 0..1`) by turning the primary key of `Child` into both PK and FK. Obviously, that doesn't work with the current situation because, for one, a primary key cannot have multiple values.

This feels like it's a common enough situation that it should have a well-known solution. However, after checking countless posts, I still can't find one. The closest thing I could find is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29189754) but it doesn't work because:

1. It creates `* to 0..1` relationships.
2. When I ignored that fact and tried to execute the following code:

   ```
   var c1 = new Child { Name = "C1" };
   var c2 = new Child { Name = "C2" };
   context.Parents.Add(new Parent { Name = "P1", PrimaryChild = c1, SecondaryChild = c2 });
   ```

   ...it threw a DbUpdateException with the message:

   > Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

How can this problem be solved?

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>This is a simplified example. In the real life scenario, there are relationships between the parent and other child entities with two or more references to each.</sub>

Comment: I wonder what is your business case that you really need such relations. I would definitely go for relation 1 to Many as it gives oprtunities to make different collection operations. And if you really want to limit amount of children to 2 i would add constraints or some validation logic

Comment: @RedgoodBreaker Thank you. Yes, I think you're right. The more I think about it, the more I become convinced that one-to-many (with a collection of children) is the way to go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code was tested in Visual Studio and works properly

```
var c1 = new Child { Name = "C1" };
var c2 = new Child { Name = "C2" };
_context.Parents.Add(new Parent { Name = "P1", PrimaryChild = c1, SecondaryChild = c2 });

var parents = _context.Parents
               .Include(i => i.PrimaryChild)
               .Include(i => i.SecondaryChild)
               .ToList();
```

To try it you have to add relations to your classes

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? PrimaryChildId { get; set; }
    public int? SecondaryChildId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PrimaryChildId))]
    [InverseProperty("PrimaryChildParents")]
    public virtual Child PrimaryChild { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(SecondaryChildId))]
    [InverseProperty("SecondaryChildParents")]
    public virtual Child SecondaryChild { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Parent.PrimaryChild))]
    public virtual ICollection<Parent> PrimaryChildParents { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Parent.SecondaryChild))]
    public virtual ICollection<Parent> SecondaryChildParents { get; set; }
}
```

if you want to make one-to-one and since  you are using EF6
you can add some constraints to the foreign keys

```
[Index("IX_Parents_PrimaryChildId", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public int? PrimaryChildId { get; set; }
      
[Index("IX_Parents_SecondaryChildId", 2, IsUnique = true)]
public int? SecondaryChildId { get; set; }
```

Comment: _"or if you have one-to-one the last 2 lines can be"_ That doesn't work. When updating the database, it throws an exception saying: `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Parents_dbo.Children_SecondaryChildId' on table 'Parents' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths`. Also, `c1` and `c2` are being created at the same time. To use `.Id`, I would have to create the children first, save changes, and get the ids. Using a collection, on the other hand, allows a single child to be linked to many parents.

Comment: @ICloneable I didn't know what version net are using. it will not work for older  net version

Comment: Older than what? I'm using .NET 4.7.2 and EF6.x as indicated by the tag. Is this answer for EF Core?

Comment: @ICloneable this is an universal answer.  You can use one-to-one only for core, for another versions use many-to-many

Comment: First of all, I did not update the question without warning. It was tagged EF6 from the very beginning. I only made it clear that the children were also being added (which I had assume was obvious) _and_ I mentioned that to you in a comment. Now, if you didn't pay attention to the tags and provided an answer for EF Core, how is that my fault? And if the close vote is yours, can you please enlighten me on what exactly isn't clear in my question? In any case, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. This indeed works. It creates one-to-many relationships but the INDEX constraints enforce one-to-one. I undid my downvote, upvoted, and will award you the bounty in a second. One remark though (please correct me if I'm wrong): because those are two _different_ indexes, the order is not really needed, right?

Comment: Also, I've made two adjustments: 1) Made the child IDs required and turned off `WillCascadeOnDelete` using Fluent API. 2) In the migration, I added a CHECK constraint to prevent both child IDs from being equal: `Sql("ALTER TABLE Parents ADD CONSTRAINT CK_ChildIds_Cannot_Be_Equal CHECK (PrimaryChildId <> SecondaryChildId);");`. Feel free to include either (or both) of them in your answer.

Comment: @ICloneable Thank you very much . I really appreciate it.  You can ask me any time if you have any questions.

Comment: Much appreciated as well. It's just that one remark about the `order` arguments (i.e., `1` and `2`) in the `[Index]` attribute. It's not needed here because they're two different indexes, right? BTW, congrats on the [10K](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) :)

Comment: IClonable Thank you for the congratulations. Order is used only for sorting and has nothing to do with unique. You are right, the order is not needed in this case since we have one column index.  The way it is now each column shoud be unique. If you want to make uniquer only combination of 2 columns, not each column you have to put the same name for index and in this case this number will affect sorting. I put it just in case. because I was not sure what do you need - each column should be unique or only combination of 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a hacky solution but I'm still hoping for a better one.

Instead of one-to-one relationships, I created a good old one-to-many relationship (`Parent` has many of `Child`) with a property in the `Child` class to store the type (primary/secondary), and created unmapped properties in the `Parent` class to replace the original navigation properties.

Here's what the code would look like for the example the question:

**`Child` class:**

```
public enum ChildType { Primary, Secondary }

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ChildType ChildType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

**`Parent` class:**

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        Children = new HashSet<Child>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Child PrimaryChild
    {
        get
        {
          return Children.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChildType == ChildType.Primary);
        }
        set
        {
         var existingChild = 
                Children.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChildType == ChildType.Primary);
            if (existingChild != null) Children.Remove(existingChild);

            Children.Add(value);
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public Child SecondaryChild
    {
        get
        {
            return Children.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChildType == ChildType.Secondary);
        }
        set
        {
            var existingChild = 
                Children.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChildType == ChildType.Secondary);
            if (existingChild != null) Children.Remove(existingChild);

            Children.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var c1 = new Child { Name = "C1", ChildType = ChildType.Primary };
var c2 = new Child { Name = "C2", ChildType = ChildType.Secondary };
context.Parents.Add(new Parent { Name = "P1", PrimaryChild = c1, SecondaryChild = c2 });
```

Obviously, this doesn't enforce the minimum or maximum number of children that the parent can have or what `ChildType` they must be. It's the best I could come up with though.

Comment: I think this is the best you can do (no idea why it was downvoted). Even in plain SQL it's pretty ugly to implement two exclusive 1:1 relationships between two tables and the 1:1 implementation in EF6 doesn't give any handles to model them.

Comment: @GertArnold Thank you. Yes, I figured it probably won't get any better than this. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious; hence, the bounty. _"no idea why it was downvoted"_ Me neither :) One downvote is (probably) from the other answerer because he got angry for no apparent reason. I don't really care about votes; it's just that downvotes on the question give it less chance of being viewed, which is another reason why I started a bounty. Thanks again for the reassurance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to create such relationships:

1. Parent has two foreign keys to the respective children, close to what you have done.
2. Children have foreign keys to the parent, which would be a simple one to many.

The first option very easily restricts a parent to two children and makes it very easy to distinguish between the primary and secondary child.

The second option, you would need to add a type to the child objects if you have the need to distinguish primary from secondary.  Using the parent's Id and the type as a unique index would allow you to limit the children to a single primary and a single secondary child per parent.

Now as far as when the parent is deleted, if you have cascading deletes for the relationship it will happen automatically.  I know that in second option, the simple one-to-many, that cascading deletes will work as expected.  The first option, basically two one-to-one relationships, you can set up cascading deletes, but I would suspect that you'll need to ensure it is a one-way cascade.  e.g. if the parent is deleted the children are too, but if a child is deleted the parent should remain.

I would lean towards the children having the foreign keys and a type.  So something along these lines:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_Child_Parent_Type", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    
    [Index("IX_Child_Parent_Type", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int ChildTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ChildType Type { get; set; }
}

public class ChildType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The other option would look like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Child PrimaryChild { get; set; }
    public virtual Child SecondaryChild { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The unique index is a nice addition to my current solution. If you be kind enough to share how the first suggestion would work, I'd appreciate that. That's what I was trying to do at first but I couldn't get it to work. I'm not sure what type of relationship it would be in that case.

Comment: ChildType and Parent can' t be columns of the table , so  you can' t  use indexes.

Comment: The other option has been added.

Comment: From the answer of another person?

Comment: @LarryDukek The second option won't work as is. It's basically the exact same code in the question. I've upvoted for the unique index idea though. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: I had left that out due to it being basically the same as your initial question's example.  I added it per your request.   I hope the index option works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
  // this class will represent a person, a parent or a child since they have the same attributes
  class Person
  {
    protected int _id;
    protected string _name; 
    public int Id { get => _id; }
    public string Name { get => _name; }
    // Any object wether it's a parent or a child must be instantiated with those properties
    public Person(int id, string name)
    {
      this._id = id;
      this._name = name;
    }
  }

  // this represents a parent which is a persone but have two persons reprenseting it's children. the children can't be instanciated alone.
  class Parent : Person
  {
    private Person _primaryChild;
    private Person _secondaryChild;
    public Person PrimaryChild { get => _primaryChild; }
    public Person SecondaryChild { get => _secondaryChild; }

    // this creates the parent with it's children. one the parent dispose its children will be deleted.
    public Parent(Person parent, Person primaryChild, Person secondaryChild) : base( parent.Id,  parent.Name)
    {
      // this primaryChild enforce that a parent must have two different children to represents a primary and a secondry child.
      if(primaryChild.Id != secondaryChild.Id)
      {
        this._id = parent.Id;
        this._name = parent.Name;
        this._primaryChild = primaryChild;
        this._secondaryChild = secondaryChild;
      }
      else
      {
        throw new Exception("Children must not be tweens.");
      }
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // instanciating a person does'nt represent an actor in the process. A parent must be instianciated.
      try
      {
        // creating a new parent with its related children
        var parent = new Parent(new Person(1, "Parent"), new Person(1, "ChildOne"), new Person(2, "ChildTwo"));
        // diplaying children names
        Console.WriteLine($"Primary Child is {parent.PrimaryChild.Name}. Secondary Child is {parent.SecondaryChild.Name}.");
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {

        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
      }
       
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my case, the parent and child cannot derive from the same class (they're totally different).

Answer (score 0):

The child class should contain a foreign key for the parent class, in this instance I've used a composite key for the one to one relationship.

```
public class Child
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Parent")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the OnModelCreating of your context you will want to set up the constraints.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.PrimaryChild)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(e => e.Parent);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.SecondaryChild)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(e => e.Parent);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
            .HasKey(e => e.ParentId);
}
```

You can extend this as you need.

Comment: That's basically what I had tried in the very beginning and it doesn't work. Have you tried it? It fails with a "Schema specified is not valid" message.

Comment: Yes I have tried something similar and have it working. Maybe you need to have the Id in the child class come from the Id in the parent class then have a ChildId as a composite key to make it unique.

Answer (score -1):

Make some small mods to the entities and use fluent api to specify a one to many relationship

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary {get; set;}
}
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id)
            .WithMany(p => p.Child)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.ParentId);
    }
    
    public DbSet<Child> Children{ get; set; }
```

Comment: This is more or less the same thing I did in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68442246/13485806) (parent has a collection of children and the child has a property to indicate whether it's primary or secondary). FYI, I did not downvote your answer though.